# How can I determine the type of a child class in C#?

Tags: c#, casting

In c#, I would like to find a way to do the following:

```
(cast_by_variable)some_class.some_method();
```

So, I would somehow like to determine the type of a child class, store the info in a variable, and then use it when the parent class use cast.

Comment: In what scenario do you need this? There might be a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct runtime cast in c# like what you are proposing but there is a workaround for this problem. You can do the following:

```
Type t = some_class_obj.GetType();
object result =t.GetMethod("some_method").Invoke(some_class_object,new object[]{parameter1,parameter2});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Object obj;

 if (some_class is Class1) 
      {
          obj = (Class1)some_class;
         // do something with obj
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Casting the object doesn't change it's type so you can always determine it with

```
some_class.GetType();

Type type = some_class.GetType();
```